# juliandate to normaldate in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

I have date like 117106, 117107 in an column which is of numeric type in redshift data base. Understood that the format is in Julian format. I wanted to change it to normal date format like yyyymmdd.

I tried applying the function to the column and it returns the value as below
select to_date(117106) - result 4393-07-10

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is done.
The way it works is the first 3 digits is the century julian offset, and the last 3 are the day offset:

```
select dateadd(day,117106 % 1000,dateadd(year,(117106 /1000),convert(datetime,'01/01/1900')))-1
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rahul for the help.

I haven't tried the solution provided.However i have implemented the below solution as below to convert it into date format

trim(cast(to_char(dateadd(days,cast(right(x)as bigint)
        + datediff(days,'1900-01-02',to_date(cast(left((1900+(x/1000)),4) as char(4)) || '-01' || '-01','yyyy-mm-dd')),'1900-01-01'),
        'YYYYMMDD')as decimal),0) as x

Answer (score 0):

Can generate_series() to cover the julian day range you need and then use standard date functions

```
with julian_day as (
select generate_series as julian_day,
       to_date(generate_series, 'J') as gregorian_date
from generate_series((2459865 - ( 10 * 365)), (2459865 + (10 * 365)), 1)
)
select
  julian_day,
   gregorian_date,
   to_char(gregorian_date, 'IYYY') as iso_year,
   date_part(year, gregorian_date) as year,
   ...
from julian_day
```