# How to convert a 5 digit Julian date in RedShift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a date column in a RedShift DB that is a 5 digit Julian. The data type is numeric. How do I convert this to date?

As an example, one value is ‘44950’, and trying to_date(*columnname*::text, ‘J’) returns 44591-12-20. Pasting this value in Excel I know it should be 2023-01-24

Comment: Might help: [juliandate to normaldate in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43513960/174777)

Comment: Thanks John. The solution you're referring to is a 6 digit Julian